# HTML make markers clickable on google maps

Tags: python, html, google-maps

I am plotting some markers using gmplot from Python. It produces an html file like this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps - pygmaps </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.670719, -74.099096);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: centerlatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.008578, -74.813284);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/FF0000.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "http://www.google.com",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10.396109, -75.518069);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/FF0000.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "http://www.google.com",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
        ... (and so on)
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

where `/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/FF0000.png` is the directory that saves the marker file. I have many points like those one, and for each point I have a URL. In this case I have put the URL as simply "http://www.google.com" in the marker's title. When I open the html file with a web browser and I hover over the markers the URL is shown to me. I would like to be able to click on the marker and make the browser open the URL. I do not have a lot of knowledge in HTML so I'm finding this rather difficult. I appreciate your help and good faith. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `marker.addEventListener ('click', function(){...});`?

Comment: @GonsaloSousa nope. What function should I use to follow the link?

Comment: Shall I do that for every marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou could add a function for manage the listener on click event for marker

```
        function initialize() {
            var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.670719, -74.099096);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                center: centerlatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            // add a function  for closure 
            var addListenersOnMarker = function(actMarker,  aTarget,) {

                google.maps.event.addListener(actMarker, 'click', function (event) {
                     window.open(aTarget, '_blank');
                });  
             }


            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.008578, -74.813284);
            var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/FF0000.png');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            //title: "http://www.google.com",
            icon: img,
            position: latlng
            });
            marker.setMap(map);

            // call the function for listener
            addListenersOnMarker( marker,  "http://www.google.com" )  ;


            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10.396109, -75.518069);
            var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/vladimir/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/FF0000.png');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            //title: "http://www.google.com",
            icon: img,
            position: latlng
            });
            marker.setMap(map);

            // call the function for listener
            addListenersOnMarker( marker,  "http://www.google.com" )  ;

            var 
            ... (and so on)

        }
```